# Valid query but still returning: "mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean etc.."

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am receiving the following error:

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean ... on line 42

I have tried to test my SQL query directly in phpmyadmin and no error occurs. I cannot see why this is happening, since the query seems valid.

The code is:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($sql_host, $sql_usr, $sql_passwd,$sql_db);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$query = "SELECT Approver_Id, Approver_Name, Approver_Email FROM Approver WHERE Approver_Name=".$username."";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) // <--- Line 42
{
    // Something top secret happens here ;)
}
```

Comment: `$username` must be inside quotes. Better use bind and prepare statement!!

Comment: write as '".$username."' and then final double quote(")

as i written here

$query = "SELECT Approver_Id, Approver_Name, Approver_Email FROM Approver WHERE Approver_Name='".$username."' ";

Comment: Learn about prepared statements